# Integration tests with Lambda [Best practice]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, integration-testing, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

My team has an AWS workflow as follows:

`SNS topic 1 -> SQS queue 1 -> Lambda 1 -> SNS Topic 2 -> SQS queue 2 -> Lambda 2 -> Call some service`

I am looking at writing integration tests for Lambda1 and Lambda2 in our beta stage and looking at the following workflow:

**Lambda1 Integration tests**

`Test SNS topic 1 -> SQS queue 1 -> Lambda 1 -> SNS Topic 2 -> Test SQS queue 2`

**Lambda2 Integration tests**

`SNS topic 2 -> SQS queue 2 -> Lambda 2 -> Test SQS queue(instead of calling service)`

So the basic workflow is I send messages to test topics and create test SQS queues from where I pop messages to verify.

1. I am concerned about both integration tests having a race condition wherein one message might be consumed by either by my test queue and the following lambda. Would the ideal scenario be to create two more test topics for `SNS Topic 2`, one each for both the lambdas?
2. Also while writing integration tests would we normally send the message to both Test and normal topics (say in `lambda1` tests, would it be normal to publish to both the normal queue and the test queue since it is beta)?
3. If I have to redirect messages based on whether it is integration tests or normal workflow what would be the ideal way(Since it is beta it should be used for integration tests mostly but `SNS topic 1` also publishes messages apart from my test SNS topic so confused)? Should I add some configuration variable to lambda or would it be better to change the payload in SNS topic/message attributes? Not really sure as I would want to make minimal amount of code changes to my lambda.

Let me know what would be the ideal testing scenario/best practice for the given workflow. Thank you.

Comment: The ideal scenario is to deploy the entire infrastructure into a testing account and then invoke whatever you want and expect some output somewhere. In this account there is no race condition because there are only the test lambdas and test queues and test topics and only your test invocation traveling through them.

Comment: Can have a race condition even in test account, if lambda1 and lambda2 integration tests run parallel, right?

Comment: Your test should not run in parallel then.